# Add arrow heads to a sequence of paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How can I add arrow heads to edges defined using a chain of `|-` notation please? Or do I just need to define multiple `\draw` calls?

In the figure below, I would also like arrow heads going into nodes `2` and `3`. Thank you.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
   \node[draw] (1) {1};
   \node[draw, below=of 1] (2) {2};
   \node[draw, below=of 2] (3) {3};
   \node[draw, below=of 3] (4) {4};

   \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (1.east) -- +(0:20mm) |- (2.east) 
                                             -- +(0:20mm) |- (3.east)
                                             -- +(0:20mm) |- (4.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: something like the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
   \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
   \node[draw] (1) {1}++(0:20mm)coordinate(aux);
   \node[draw, below=of 1] (2) {2};
   \node[draw, below=of 2] (3) {3};
   \node[draw, below=of 3] (4) {4};

   \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (1) -|(aux);
   \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-]  (2)-|(aux);
   \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (3)-|(aux);
   \draw[red, ]  (4)-|(aux);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the same result with `foreach` loop

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
   \node[draw] (1) {1}++(0:20mm)coordinate(aux);
   \foreach \X [count=\xi]in {2,3,4}{%
   \node[draw, below=of \xi] (\X) {\X};
 }

\foreach \Y in {1,2,3}{
   \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (\Y) -|(aux);
    \draw[red, ]  (4)-|(aux);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks js bibra; That does reduce the typing of the multiple `\draw` calls which I had tried  (i.e. `\draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (1.east) -- +(0:20mm) |- (2.east) ;    \draw[red, {Latex[length=5mm]}-] (2.east) -- +(0:20mm) |- (3.east);` etc). So multiple `\draw` calls are required?

Comment: `foreach` can also be used but the savings are minimal so .....

Comment: i have added a `foreach` loop -- would you like to accept the answer

Comment: @user20650 --- i have added a `foreach` loop -- would you like to accept the answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way with TikZ. Change values of `\a` and `\b` as you want. The option `minimum size=5mm` makes vertical alignment of box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2}   \def\b{.65}
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{
\path (0,-\i*\b) node[draw,red,rounded corners,minimum size=5mm] (A\i) {\i};
\draw[stealth-] (A\i.east)-|(\a,-\b);
}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```